# How to sort the collection List by the latest(datetime) field?

Tags: c#

I have a list of fields and I want to sort by the Latest date a field type datetime

```
foreach (var item in PList)
{                        
      SchemaPermis schemaPermis = new SchemaPermis();

      schemaPermis.PE_NUMERO = item.PE_NUMERO;
      schemaPermis.PE_REFERENCE = item.PE_REFERENCE;
      schemaPermis.PE_COUT_PREVU = item.PE_COUT_PREVU;
      schemaPermis.PE_DATE_FIN = item.PE_DATE_FIN;
      schemaPermis.PE_AUTRE_OBJET = item.PE_AUTRE_OBJET;

      PermisList.Add(schemaPermis);                     
}
```

I need to be able to sort the collection List by the latest(datetime) field.

Comment: What means _latest_, you you want to sort descending by this datetime field or do you want to get the latest `SchemaPermis` object from the list? Also, which list to you want to sort at all?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to sort `PList` or `PermisList`? However, you can use LINQ's `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`:

```
var orderedPermaList = PermisList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PE_DATE_FIN);
```

If you need a `List<SchemaPermis>` use `ToList()`.

But what  means *latest* at all? Do you you want to sort descending by this datetime field or do you want to get the latest `SchemaPermis` object from the list?

If you want a single object, the latest `SchemaPermis` in the list:

```
SchemaPermis lastPerma = PermisList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PE_DATE_FIN)
    .First();
```

If you want to modify the original list instead of creating a new one (with `ToList`) you can use the [overload of `List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to multiply with -1 to get descending order:

```
permaList.Sort((p1, p2) => -1 * p1.PE_DATE_FIN.CompareTo(p2.PE_DATE_FIN));
```

Comment: Note that this will not sort the list in place. It will create an `IEnumerable` over the original list, and if you call `ToList` will create an entirely new list.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: point taken, edited my answer to provide also List.Sort.

Comment: Surprisingly (I've only just tested this and seen), the other way to get descending order is to compare right to left, instead of left to right (or in this case p2 to p1 instead of p1 to p2).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: that's simpler, strange that i've never thought of it. However, both are less readable than LINQ but probably a little bit more efficient.

Comment: True, I tend to prefer readability over most things, but as always it is a judgement call on the situation (namely the amount of data and intended usage of the list). For most small lists the difference is negligible. The non-linq, fluently readable way is to use method-group syntax for the delegate: `private static int ByDateDescending(SchemaPermis l, SchemaPermis r) { ... };  list.Sort(ByDateDescending);`

Comment: Small point, but rather than using `-1*` to negate, you can just use `-`: `-p1.PE_DATE_FIN.CompareTo(p2.PE_DATE_FIN)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var orderedList = PermisList.OrderBy(item => item.LatestDate);
```